# Chrome Extension how to get notified that background script is to be closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let me explain. My Google Chrome Extension saves its state in the `chrome.storage.local` persistent storage. The amount of data can be quite substantial (up to several MB in JSON layout) and thus I am not calling `chrome.storage.local.set()` every time a change occurs to minimize the impact of my extension on the system it runs on. Instead I do the saving on timer, in the background, currently every 30 seconds.

This background saving process happens in the *background script* that stays in memory for as long as my extension is running. (I set `"background": {"persistent": true}` in the `manifest.json` file.)

The issue happens when my extension is re-installed or unloaded, as some of its state in between those 30 second saves is lost.

So I was wondering if there's any way for me to track the moment when the background script is about to be closed? (So that I can save my app's state.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept an update with a listener for the [`chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable` event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable):

> Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running. If you do nothing, the update will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded, if you want it to be installed sooner you can explicitly call chrome.runtime.reload(). If your extension is using a persistent background page, the background page of course never gets unloaded, so unless you call chrome.runtime.reload() manually in response to this event the update will not get installed until the next time chrome itself restarts. If no handlers are listening for this event, and your extension has a persistent background page, it behaves as if chrome.runtime.reload() is called in response to this event.

As for unloading.. If you mean being disabled by the user, there's probably no way for cleanup to happen, but don't quote me on that.

You can try listening to [`chrome.runtime.onSuspend`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onSuspend) even if you use a persistent page, or even `window.onunload`. I don't know, just throwing out ideas. In either of those cases you'll have a very limited time to clean up.

If you want to clean up upon browser being closed, you can try playing with the `"background"` permission and listening for windows being created and closed. That way you extend the lifetime beyond browser closing, unless the user explicitly disables background apps.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I tried `chrome.runtime.onSuspend` and to the best of my knowledge, it was not called. `window.onunload` wasn't called for reloading the extension either, but from what I can find it may be called when Chrome itself is closed. Hmm. It's interesting that there's no uniform notification for that, hah?

Comment: Explicit extension reload / disable is analogous to unplugging a power cord. So there's very little hope to intercept that, but it should not happen normally.

Comment: Well, a user can go to Settings -> Extensions and click "Reload (Ctrl+R)" link for my app. It's not that uncommon, is it?

Comment: Depends, heavily, on who your users are. No, users _don't_ do that normally.